# Unfamiliar with Sass, I think there is a small syntax issue in my main.scss keeping me from compiling

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I'm setting up a Jekyll page and the current theme I'm using uses Sass, but GitHub pages (where I'm hosting it) does not support Sass. So I'm trying to convert my .scss files to .css but I'm getting the an error on this file:

```
---
---

@import 'syntax';

$site-background-color: #f5f5f5;
$contrast-color: #333;

$azul-accent-color: #0070bb;
$ruby-accent-color: #e0115f;
$amber-accent-color: #ff7e00;
$avocado-accent-color: #568203;

/*============================================================================*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: $site-background-color;
  border-top: 5px solid $contrast-color;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: $contrast-color;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, dl,
blockquote,
table,
img,
hr,
.fluid-width-video-wrapper,
.highlight {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

blockquote {
  padding: 0 30px;
  border-left: 2px solid darken($site-background-color, 15%);
}

ul, ol {
  margin-left: 40px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

hr {
  border : 0;
  height: 25px;
  background : url(/public/images/eagle.png) center center no-repeat;
}

code {
  font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

p code {
  padding: 0px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid $contrast-color;

  td, th {
    border: 1px solid $contrast-color;
    padding: 5px 10px;
  }

  thead {
    background-color: darken($site-background-color, 10%);
  }
}

// TODO: make dt smaller
dt {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}

footer {
  font-size: .8rem;
  text-align: center;
}

/*============================================================================*/
.azul { a { color: $azul-accent-color;
    &:hover { color: darken($azul-accent-color, 20%);
}}}

.ruby { a { color: $ruby-accent-color;
    &:hover { color: darken($ruby-accent-color, 20%);
}}}

.amber { a { color: $amber-accent-color;
    &:hover { color: darken($amber-accent-color, 20%);
}}}

.avocado { a { color: $avocado-accent-color;
    &:hover { color: darken($avocado-accent-color, 20%);
}}}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.highlight {
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #272822;
  color: #f8f8f2;
  line-height: 1;

  code {
    font-size: .7rem;
  }
}

.container {
  max-width: 750px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 20px 20px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.top-navbar {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  height: 110px;

  a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: $contrast-color;
    padding: 66px 20px 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lighten($contrast-color, 10%);
    transition: all ease-in-out .3s;

    &:hover,
    &.current-page {
      color: $site-background-color;
      border-bottom: none;
    }

    &:hover {
      background-color: $contrast-color;
      transform: translateY(5px);
    }

    &.current-page {
      background-color: $contrast-color;
    }
  }
}

.archive,
.single {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.single {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.single time {
  color: #999;
  font-size: .9rem;
}

.bundle {
  border-top: 1px solid lighten($contrast-color, 50%);
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.post-date {
  text-align: right;
}

.not-found {
  margin-top: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.not-found h1 {
  font-size: 8rem;
}

dl,
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

dl,
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*============================================================================*/
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 110px;
  width: 110px;
  background-size: 90px 90px;
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/*============================================================================*/
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .top-navbar {
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;

    a {
      padding: 5px 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      border-radius: 0;
      border: 1px solid $contrast-color;
      transition: none;

      &:hover {
        transform: none;
      }
    }
  }

  .bundle,
  .post-date {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .bundle article {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  #logo {
    background-position: center center;
  }
}
```

The error is:

```
Line 1: Invalid CSS after "-": expected number or function, was "--"
```

I imagine there is a quick fix for this that I am missing since I am not familiar with Sass at all. Am I right? Anyone know how I can fix this?

Also, I'm using the following command to convert from scss to css `sass --watch main.scss:main.css` if anyone knows of a better way please let me know!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two lines of `---` at the beginning of your file; what is it you think they're doing? Remove them, they're syntactically invalid and they're causing your errors.

Comment: Gah, I don't know why I didn't at least try that before asking. It worked, thanks so much!

Comment: I assume they were meant as the end of the YAML part of a source file. But since the scss is not converted to css by Jekyll, there is no need for it.

Comment: Jekyll does convert Sass, since v2 and they are required.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll 2 brings native Sass compilation and the two lines of triple dashes are in fact *required* in order for Jekyll to compile the Sass file:

http://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/

If you are not yet using Jekyll 2, then this will not work of course. If you are using Jekyll 2 then you can do this and no longer require a sass --watch command, Jekyll will do that automagically.

Answer (score 0):

you probably had the same problem as me that the _config.yml is not at your root directory. If you don't want to change your file structure, you can set a new repo and add the jekyll files in a new gh-pages branch. I wrote a blog about it: http://shinshinwu.github.io/myblog/jekyll/update/2014/12/21/welcome-to-jekyll.html